# How to open a file using exec command in php?

Tags: cakephp, command-line, exec

I am trying to open a file by using the exec command in cake php controller.
I have written a simple function with

```
echo exec('cd\users\Sathya\Desktop');
echo exec('key.txt');
```

The command `cd\users\Sathya\Desktop` followed by `key.txt` opens the required file when i type this command on the command line interface. But I am unable to do the same with from my php file.

I also do not get a nt authority system error message in this case.
But when i put `echo exec('whoami');` in the php file, i get windows nt authority system error message.

Please tell me how to solve this problem. 
Am I following an entirely wrong approach? I am new to php, so any help will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you *really* want to do? Perhaps `$key = file_get_contents('/users/Sathya/Desktop/key.txt')`?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @deceze in comment, `file_get_contents` function is what you are seeking for.

```
$key = file_get_contents('/users/Sathya/Desktop/key.txt');
```

and the variable `$key` will contain the contents of the text file.

Comment: When I do this, I get the message "No such file or directory".
Is there any problem with the path that i have specified?

Comment: Not sure. The file is on your computer. Double check with user rights.

Answer (score 0):

Also - you're dealing with a windows file system -- try changing your "/" to "\" and ensuring the root volume is in fact accessible.

Perhaps put the `key.txt` into your application's folder.